# adding quotes around date and time, c#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I am currently using the following line:

```
w.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy,HH:mm:ss"));
```

and it gives and output like:

```
05/23/2011,14:24:54
```

What I need is quotations around the date and time, the output should look like this:

```
"05/23/2011","14:24:54"
```

any thoughts on how to "break up" datetime, and get quotes around each piece?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `String.Format`:

```
w.Write(String.Format("\"{0:MM/dd/yyyy}\",\"{0:HH:mm:ss}\"", DateTime.Now));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("\\\"MM/dd/yyyy\\\",\\\"HH:mm:ss\\\"")
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick, too.

```
  string format = @"{0:\""MM/dd/yyyy\"",\""HH:mm:ss\""}" ;
  string s = string.Format(format,DateTime.Now) ;
```

as will this:

```
string format = @"{0:'\""'MM/dd/yyyy'\""','\""'HH:mm:ss'\""'}" ;
string s = string.Format(format,DateTime.Now) ;
```

and this

```
string format = @"{0:""\""""MM/dd/yyyy""\"""",""\""""HH:mm:ss""\""""}" ;
string s = string.Format(format,DateTime.Now) ;
```

The introduction of a literal double quote (`"`) or apostrophe (`'`) in a DateTime or Numeric format strings introduces literal text. The embedded literal quote/apostrophe must be balanced — they act as an embedded quoted string literal in the format string. To get a double quote or apostrophe it needs to be preceded with a backslash.

[John Sheehan's formatting cheatsheets](http://john-sheehan.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/msnet-formatting-strings.pdf) makes note of this...feature, but insofar as I can tell, the CLR documentation is (and always has been) incorrect WRT this: the docs on custom date/time and numeric format strings just says that "[any other character] is copied to the result string unchanged.".

Answer (score 0):

The following version, though obvious, will not work:

```
w.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("\"MM/dd/yyyy\",\"HH:mm:ss\""));
```

This will output:

> MM/dd/yyyy,HH:mm:ss

So don't do that.

Comment: That was my first guess as well but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @ashelvey @user630581 - I have updated my answer with this information.

Comment: +1, cause you can't fault somebody for trusting the documentation. See my answer for details as to why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string part1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        string part2 = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
        Console.WriteLine("\""+part1+"\",\""+part2+"\"");
```

Works just fine. May not be the best way though

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the type of `w` but if it supports the standard set of `Write` overloads the following should work.

```
w.Write(@"""{0}""", DateTime.Now.ToString(@"MM/dd/yyyy"",""HH:mm:ss")));
```

If not then you can do the following

```
var msg = String.Format(@"""{0}""", DateTime.Now.ToString(@"MM/dd/yyyy"",""HH:mm:ss"))));
w.Write(msg);
```

Comment: Missing the quotes around the comma, as per the OP.